# Windows 7 - Lesser options in disk management

Tags: windows-7, disk-management

On my laptop, I can see these options in disk management:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9vyreiscw427my/DM1.png?dl=0

I need to make new mirrored volume for RAID 1 on my desktop, but I don't see them when I click on any of my 4 drives:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ni6he5bd7rp62ib/DM2.png?dl=0

Both computers have Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate, disabled unneeded services. (www_techrepublic_com/blog/10-things/10-plus-windows-7-services-you-may-not-need/)

I don't have any idea why it doesn't work, except services (I disabled even more on laptop).

Comment: I do not think it is a service being on or off, it is not because of a specific disk "type", as that would be different items in the menu.  I wonder if it is the permission of the user?  Also you could take a look in (all) the properties, including driver details, for some clue of some sort?  Any group policy that keeps that from being touched.

Comment: I was logged as Administrator, it's weird. I can create simple/spanned/stripped volume when I click on unallocated partition. I went with bios RAID, which is anyway better option.

Comment: You will then be using the "hardware" raid then, not relying on the operating system to be the one assembling the disks, sounds like a much better choice IMO (meaning each has some ramification).